# Why is my PC still working after it goes to sleep mode?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, fan

I normally don't shut down my Laptop. After I worked, I let it go into sleep mode.
But often, especially at night, I can hear laptop fans' loud noises when it is in the sleep mode. Usually, my laptop fans start working only when some heavy processes are being done. (Ex: Virus scan, Gaming, etc)

When I turn it back to normal mode using power button (It does not start with pressing keys or moving mouse) to see what's going on, it will stop all the fans and only then it'll show me the Login Screen. Also, When it's on, task manager does not show me any abnormal usage of resources.

I know that this can be a virus scan or Windows maintain (since it's on). But this also can be a malware or, some bot is using my PC to do some illegal work.

So, Is this normal?
how can I be sure that this is okay?
Is there any way to know the applications that were active in the sleep mode?

Laptop Brand: Gigabyte
OS: Windows 10.0.16299.125
Virus Guard: Windows Defender & Sophos Home (Sophos Virus guard doesn't have lots maintain options)
Internet: connected all the time.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe, this is due to a Windows maintain or windows update. But I like it to be sure. Because I have been using Windows & this PC for a long time, but I haven't faced this kind of issue earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the Windows Event Log to read the OS history. That may reveal something interesting.

Doe this occur only at certain times of the month? 
I ask cause I suspect that it is Windows Update. To test it, run Windows Update before you put it to sleep. Make sure it finished, then put it to sleep.

Comment: Thank you. 
I'll check Windows Event log. But for now, Windows update is up to date.
Also, I don't think this happens every day. But I do think that this happens most of the times.